# How to replace a string after a single char?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string like this `String no1="c1245_f5";` and I have another one String like this `String no2="456df";` and I want to replace the first string by the second string but after the first character only.

In this I have replace after c. My Output has to be like c456df . I don't have any idea of doing this.I tried up to replacing the whole string

```
String no2="456df";
String no1="c1245_f5";
int g;
g=no1.indexOf("c");
int h=no1.indexOf("_", g+1);
no1=no1.substring(g, h);

System.out.println("Number-"+no1);

String rep=no1.replaceAll(no1,no2);

System.out.println(rep);
```

Here the output is second string only.

**Edit:**

The expected Output :

```
c456df
```

The output I'm Getting :

```
456df
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what you getting?

Comment: so what output are you expecting?

Comment: write the output you want

Comment: Could I please ask what is the purpose of doing this? What does "c456df" mean?

Comment: check my response in the lower part. The mistake that you are making is that you should consider the first position after the 'c' character. So the indexOf('c') + 1.

Comment: This is small thing which I need to do it inside my code.Also I need to get string after the underscore.but now I got everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then create a string s3 by concatenating  `s1.substring(0, 1)` and  `s2`

```
String s1 ="c1245_f5";
String s2 = "456df";
String s3 = s1.substring(0, 1) + s2;
```

It will give the output `c456df`

[**SEE HERE**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm)

Comment: Yes I solved..Can't accept any answer..It asking me to wait 9 minutes

Answer (score 5):

no need for String.replaceAll, try this

```
    String s1 ="c1245_f5";
    String s2 = "456df";
    String s3 = s1.substring(0, 1) + s2;
```

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing, that came to my mind is to use `String.substring(int,int)`.

So the code would be something like this:

```
String tmp=c1.substring(0,1)+no2;
System.out.println(tmp);
```

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to get more info about functions of `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
String no1 = "c1245_f5";
String no2 = "456df";
String no3 = no1.charAt(0) + no2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use this:

```
String rep = no1.replace(no1.substring(1), no2);
```

The mistake that you are making is that you should consider the first position after the 'c' character. So the indexOf('c') + 1

Put in your code that should be:

> ```
>   String no2="456df";
>   String no1="c1245_f5";
>   String rep = no1.replace(no1.substring(no1.indexOf("c")+1), no2);
>   System.out.println(rep);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Take the index, then append the second String.

```
String s1 ="c1245_f5";
String index = s1.substring(0, 1)
String s2 = index + "456df";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String no1 ="c1245_f5";
String no2= "456df";
int len=no1.length();
String no3= no1.substring(1,len);
String newNo1=no1.replace(s3, s2);
```